# How to strip column values in Active record through loop before saving in rails framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have to remove spaces for every record before saving into the database.
I can do that by specifying it for each column, but when there 100 columns in each record, it is a pain and no of lines of code increases enormously.

Need help in changing the code into a loop, but being an amateur in rails I am not able to complete it.

```
class hello < ActiveRecord::Base

before_validation :remove_spaces  

def remove_spaces
          self.login = self.login.strip if self.login.present?
          self.email = self.email.strip if self.email.present?
          . so on .......

      end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `attributes.each` to iterate over all attribute names and the values of the current instance (while ignoring the attribute names).

For each value I would call `try(:strip!)` to strip whitespace from the value. Please note that `try` only calls `strip!` on values that actually `respond_to?(:strip!)` which means basically just on strings, therefore it would ignore `nil` values or values of unsupported types, like timestamps or booleans.

```
before_validation :sanitize_strings

private
def sanitize_strings
  attributes.each { |_, value| value.try(:strip!) }
end
```

Or when you only want to sanitize specific attributes, then you can just iterate over their names:

```
ATTRIBUTES_TO_SANITIZE = %i[name title description]

def sanitize_strings
  ATTRIBUTES_TO_SANITIZE.each { |attr| send(attr).try(:strip!) }
end
```

Comment: But would this approach similar to using SELF for each attribute?

Comment: Also I think you meant `each { |_,value| #...}` because the hyphen (or unary `-`) will raise a syntax error.

Comment: And if necessary, how do I do the same for specific columns rather than all the columns?

Comment: @Donejob I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for the quick reply, please check the following code. def sanitize d_attributes = [ "first_name" ] d_attributes.each { |attr| send(attr).try(:strip!) } end is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all column names of type string as:

```
list = Model.columns.select { |x| x.name if x.type == :string }.map(&:name)
```

Now you can apply strip over each columns with a loop

```
list.each { |x| self.send(x.to_sym)&.strip! }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `select { |x|   x.type == :string}.map(&:name)` would be more idiomatic than `map{#...}.compact` in addition given the rails 3 tag it is reasonable to assume this is not ruby >= 2.3 so safe navigation `&.` is likely a no go.